# How to localize content blocks in css?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, localization

So as has become fairly common practice we are using css content to position text that is really "style" specific. eg

```
.label:after { content: ":"; }
```

it was pointed out to me however that this sort of thing varies in certain cultures. Uh oh.

Does anyone have a good pattern for dealing with this sort of thing since CSS files are not typically passed through an asp.net processor and therefore have no access to the resources files.

Comment: It sounds like you want the value of `content` to come from the server side?

Comment: @MarcAudet the value of content *does* come from the server - the entire css file is of coure on the server, but typically differences in localization are defined in resource files which are swapped based on thread culture. However, css gets served as content directly by the web server so asp.net never gets a chance to process it.

Comment: Are the cultural adjustments be one-to-one with language? e.g. in a page with `lang` as hebrew, this would always use `.label:before` instead of `.label:after`?

Comment: @DavidWoods I'm not certain but I *think* the browser takes care of that for you if the text-direction is switched?

Comment: Yes I had to experiment to verify but yes the browser does appear to switch before/after depending on rtl -- [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ4rn/)

Answer (score 11):

I really like this question so I thought about it a bit. Would this be a good approach for you?

```
<label data-after=":">Name</label>
```

Then, in your CSS you can do:

```
label:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
}
```

Here's a quick demo of it:
http://jsbin.com/iYEKOH/1/edit?html,css,output

It should be pretty easy to polyfill for browsers that don't support it using Modernizr. I think it would add a `no-generatedcontent` class.

---

Another though... How about this approach?

```
html label:after { content: '' }
html[lang=en] label:after { content: ':' }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I had forgot all about the `attr` function. However, I think the big problem with this is that it's not terribly different from just placing a `:` in the content (admittedly it's better for screen readers). I am still stuck in adding this to *every* label in my application. This could of course be abstracted with a razor function or an Html helper but that seems like hacks to solve hacks.

Comment: Yeah, but then when you add support for a culture you have to add a resource file AND remember to make this one change in css. Not the worst thing ever, just still hacky.

Comment: Bill beat me to that answer with his edit, that's what I was going after when I posted the comment to the OP. I think this is the DRYest solution, and follows the typical CSS override pattern.

Comment: You could even do `html[dir=ltr]` one thing and `html[dir=rtl]` the other.

Comment: Changing styles based on the lang attribute is going to be your best bet.  Using the `data-*` attributes with the `attr()` expression is better suited for containing localized text.

Comment: Minor point of order - You should probably put your second solution in a separate answer.

Comment: I've make it a separate answer.

Comment: Your first solution is brilliant. I think this whole answer should be accepted as the valid answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

How about this approach? It'll let you switch it up based on the `lang` attribute.

```
html label:after { content: '' }
html[lang=en] label:after { content: ':' }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this in PHP (the scripting language is not critical, just affects the implementation details), I would set up CSS files that contains all the rules that depend on the localization.

For example, `local-en.css`, `local-fr.css` and so on.

In my site template(s), I would check my localization flag and then load or link to the appropriate CSS file taking into account the order of the files to make sure that all the CSS rules cascade correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like yet another localization mechanism but it got pointed out to me by a coworker that for extreme localization the icons you use might actually differ by culture in which case this becomes the simplest solution.

Comment: I think the aim here is to organize the server side file structure to simplify maintenance in the future.  You want to be able to extend the localization features by touching as few files as possible.  It might take 1 or 2 design iterations until you find something that works smoothly with your file/db structure.